# Get available strong authentication devices fails after JIT-migration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are in the process of moving to Azure AD B2C and are using a migration flow based on the example here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/jit-migration-v1.

The issue we are facing is that sometimes after migrating and signin in a user, the user is sent to an error page. Looking at the audit log in the Azure Portal we can see that it fails on activity type "Get available strong authentication devices" with status reason "Internal server error".

It doesn't fail all the time, sometimes everything works fine, and even when it fails the migration part works as expected (the user can back out from the error page and sign in again with no error). It only happens when the user is migrated, i.e. a normal sign in works all the time.

The API call basically does this:

1. Check if user already is migrated
2. If not migrated, verify signinname and password
3. Add the user to Azure AD B2C
4. Wait a couple of seconds before returning (don't know if this really is needed, but the example code had this as well).

The custom policy basically looks like the template found here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp.

The only addition if the the technicalprofile SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email, which adds the validationtechnicalprofile to make the API call.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-SignIn" ContinueOnError="false" />
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Any way to troubleshoot this issue further?

Answer (score 1):

The error could be caused by the `AzureMfa-GetAvailableDevices` Technical Profile not finding the user. Try increasing the wait time after its creation.